# Separar uno a uno los elementos de una cadena de texto con Python

Tags: python, string, dataframe

Buenas tardes para todos, estoy trabajando con un dataframe que genere a partir de una consulta SQL, quiero obtener uno a uno los elementos (por separado) de una sola columna del dataframe. Al obtener los valores de la columna escogida obtengo un "str" con todos los valores juntos, ¿Cómo puedo extraer uno a uno los valores iterando para no hacerlo de uno en uno y como podría guardarlos con extensión ".txt" en mi computador? Adjunto las sentencias que estoy usando, Saludos cordiales

```
sql='SELECT * FROM CAT_ACTECONOMICA'

df=pd.read_sql_query(sql, conexion)

for i in range(len(df)):
    output=df['CAEDESCRIPCION'].iloc[i]
    print(output)
```

El resultado en consola es:

ELABORACIÓN DE COMBUSTIBLE NUCLEAR
FABRICACIÓN DE SUSTANCIAS QUÍMICAS BÁSICAS, EXCEPTO ABONOS Y COMPUESTOS DE NITRÓGENO
FABRICACIÓN DE ABONOS Y COMPUESTOS DE NITRÓGENO
FABRICACIÓN DE PLÁSTICOS EN FORMAS PRIMARIAS Y DE CAUCHO SINTÉTICO
FABRICACIÓN DE PLAGUICIDAS Y OTROS PRODUCTOS QUÍMICOS DE USO AGROPECUARIO
FABRICACIÓN DE PINTURAS, BARNICES Y PRODUCTOS DE REVESTIMIENTOS SIMILARES, TINTAS DE IMPRENTA Y MASILLAS
FABRICACIÓN DE PRODUCTOS FARMACÉUTICOS, SUSTANCIAS QUÍMICAS MEDICINALES Y PRODUCTOS BOTÁNICOS
FABRICACIÓN DE JABONES Y DETERGENTES, PREPARADOS PARA LIMPIAR Y PULIR, PERFUMES Y PREPARADOS DE TOCADOR
FABRICACIÓN DE OTROS PRODUCTOS QUÍMICOS, NO CLASIFICADOS EN OTRA PARTE
FABRICACIÓN DE FIBRAS MANUFACTURADAS
FABRICACIÓN DE CUBIERTAS Y CÁMARAS DE CAUCHO; REENCAUCHADO Y RENOVACIÓN DE CUBIERTAS DE CAUCHO
...

Comment: ¿Puedes pasar un dataset de cómo están tus datos para poder hacer pruebas? En relación a tu pregunta, no sé si se podría hacer con split a lo mejor.

Comment: Buen día, aparte de incluir el `dataset` como lo solicitó Esei, ¿Puedes incluir el resultado esperado? Por lo que veo, cada resultado es una frase y no palabras, tendrías que ver cual es el separador de resultados.

Comment: No sé si es esto: utilizas `print`, por lo tanto, no se manda un fin de línea. Por eso ves todo junto. Si utilizas `println` verás que cada valor se inicia en una línea separada.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich print envía un salto de linea por default una vez que todo fue mostrado en pantalla. De cualquier modo, println no es una función built-in de Python.

Comment: La verdad no está muy claro lo que quieres hacer pero si te quieres llevar guardar los valores de una columna a text utiliza: df.to_csv("archivo.txt",index=False,columna=["CAEDESCRIPCION"] ). En todo caso detalla que quieres hacer porque no es muy claro.